Why in pytorch lightning isn't the previous validation step deleted from logging in console?
Why does my console log the validation as follows? For the Epochs the earlier percentage is always replaced by the latest so that there is only 100% in the end. But for the validation, every 10% is getting logged and not deleted.
This is the log:
Epoch 0:   0%|          | 0/40 [00:00<?, ?it/s] The 'train_dataloader' does not have many workers which may be a bottleneck. Consider increasing the value of the `num_workers` argument` to 'num_workers=15' in the `DataLoader` to improve performance.`

I am expecting the same behavior for the validation as for the epochs.
Epoch 0: 100%|██████████| 40/40 [02:04<00:00,  0.32it/s, v_num=11]Epoch 0, global step 40: 'val_loss' reached 3.21670 (best 3.21670), saving model to ... as top 1

Validation: |          | 0/? [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Validation:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  10%|█         | 1/10 [00:00<00:05,  1.71it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  20%|██        | 2/10 [00:01<00:05,  1.52it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  30%|███       | 3/10 [00:02<00:04,  1.41it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  40%|████      | 4/10 [00:02<00:04,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  50%|█████     | 5/10 [00:03<00:03,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  60%|██████    | 6/10 [00:04<00:02,  1.40it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  70%|███████   | 7/10 [00:05<00:02,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  80%|████████  | 8/10 [00:05<00:01,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  90%|█████████ | 9/10 [00:06<00:00,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0: 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:07<00:00,  1.39it/s]

Epoch 0: 100%|██████████| 40/40 [02:04<00:00,  0.32it/s, v_num=11]
Epoch 0, global step 40: 'val_loss' reached 3.21670 (best 3.21670), saving model to ... as top 1

Epoch 1: 100%|██████████| 40/40 [01:59<00:00,  0.34it/s, v_num=11]

Validation: |          | 0/? [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Validation:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:   0%|          | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  10%|█         | 1/10 [00:00<00:05,  1.71it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  20%|██        | 2/10 [00:01<00:05,  1.52it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  30%|███       | 3/10 [00:02<00:04,  1.41it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  40%|████      | 4/10 [00:02<00:04,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  50%|█████     | 5/10 [00:03<00:03,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  60%|██████    | 6/10 [00:04<00:02,  1.40it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  70%|███████   | 7/10 [00:05<00:02,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  80%|████████  | 8/10 [00:05<00:01,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0:  90%|█████████ | 9/10 [00:06<00:00,  1.39it/s]
Validation DataLoader 0: 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:07<00:00,  1.39it/s]

Epoch 1: 100%|██████████| 40/40 [02:06<00:00,  0.32it/s, 'v_num=11']Epoch 1, global step 80: 'val_loss' reached 2.01761 (best 2.01761), saving model to ... as top 1


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
